# Providing arrays as parameters to devops pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, devops

I'm just getting started with azure pipelines. We're wanting to move away from manually deploying our Azure resources with arm templates and parameter files to do doing so with a devops pipeline.

While it's straightforward to do this with a single template+parameter's json file, I cannot see a sensible way to do with with multiple files.

I've seen discussions concerning using an array as a parameter to a pipeline template - this would work, but I cannot see how to create the parameter array other than setting it manually in the pipeline yaml file.

A more useful solution would be either by reading its contents in from a text file- which we could generate before the file is read, or - even more ideally- by referencing a directory listing of the folder within the repo containing the json parameter files for the template that's common to them all.

A code fragment within the yaml pipeline is capable of passing back a single string variable E.g.

```
script: |
      # Get list of files in folder
      $fl =  get-childitem ./templates | select-object -expand name
      Write-output  "##vso[task.setvariable variable=fl]$fl"
```

But all this produces is a single string which I cannot then split.

Similarly, I can use a fragment of code to dynamically create the file listing - but again, cannot see how to read that within the pipeline.

Is there an approach that lets my dynamically set the content of the parameter array within an devops pipeline, or read the array in from a file?

Or should i just give up and write the entire thing in a powershell script and use a task to run that instead of trying to use the azure deployment tasks in a devops?

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 6):

1.Read the String file and split the string into an array on the yaml

Create a yaml build and add the task power shell. We also can use the extension [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to update the value of file

```
$ourfiles = Get-Content "file path"
Write-Output $ourfiles

$CharArray =$ourfiles.Split(" ")
$CharArray
```

2.We also can use each in the yaml, please refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#extend-from-a-template) for more details.

Template file: test.yml

```
parameters:
- name: InstanceArgs 
  type: object
  default: [] 
stages:
  - stage: deploy
    displayName: deploy
    jobs:
      - ${{ each arg in parameters.InstanceArgs }}:
        - deployment: ${{ arg.value }}
          displayName: ${{ arg.value }}
          environment: Development
          strategy:
            runOnce:
              deploy:
                steps:
                - script: echo Hello, world!
```

YAML build

```
extends:
  template: test.yml
  parameters:
    InstanceArgs:  
      In1 : _1
      In2 : _2
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. 
Following the notes at: 
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#using-custom-variables]

Suggests something like 
`Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=fileList]$fileList"`
But this just sends back a space delimited string, rather than an Array.  Attempting to use write-host with a -separator modifier doesn't work either.

Your second example is great - but I'm still stuck with my original problem of how do I get the array of parameter's into the parameter list, apart from hardcoding.

Comment: As a workaround, we can store variables in the josn file and read the file via power shell command, then call the API to set these variables

Comment: thanks - but I think the underlying problem is a string variable is of no use - I need an Array, and this just isn't a thing in Pipelines.  Arrays can exist as Parameters  - so if I could read the Parameters from a file, that would work well. But I can't see how to do that either. Thanks for the coment.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this @DaveF?

Comment: Haha same issue here. Any developments?

Comment: My hack solution for a similar issue was to format the array in the YAML file as a string in a comma separated variable (CSV) format.  This CSV string is then passed to a BICEP string parameter.  Inside the BICEP file, the CSV is converted to an array using the `split()` function.   I couldn't find any other way to pass an array from a YAML file to a BICEP array parameter... at least not yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `extends` to create a pipeline template that deploys your resources. This can have a parameter for the resources you want to deploy, including arm template + param files array, and then loop through them using `foreach`. Then you can hard-code your resources into params of multiple pipelines, with the trigger filtered by branch/path/your other criteria, which pass these params into the template.