# Getting values from a command in yaml parameter

Tags: azure-devops, parameters, yaml, azure-pipelines

When storing an array in the Azure pipeline yaml parameter, I normally declare the type object that looks something like this:

```
parameters:
    - name: versions
      type: object
      default:
        - 3.0.1
        - 3.0.2
        - 3.0.3
```

But now, the issue is I don't know this array set of versions and I have to get it from a command.
So I was thinking something like this:

```
parameters:
    - name: versions
      type: object
      default: $npm view @get-versions
```

But it does not seem to work. Does anyone know how to get values from command for the parameter in yaml pipeline? I appreciate it so much!

Comment: not sure if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62934693/providing-arrays-as-parameters-to-devops-pipelines

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Parameters need to be pre-defined and cannot be dynamically generated.

The ugly workaround would be to write an application that parses and updates the pipeline YAML when a new version of your package is published. An alternative is to just make the parameter value a free-form text field, with a reasonable default.